# Using Keyring in cx_Freeze : No recommended backend was available

Tags: python, windows-10, cx-freeze, python-keyring

I am trying to build an exe file using cx_Freeze from target.py which has an import of keyring in the code. I succeeded in building the exe file, but calls an error saying "No recommended backend was available. Install the keyrings.alt package if you want to use the non-recommended backends. See README.rst for details." I used PyInstaller, but got the same error. I have found the link for ketrings.alt (https://github.com/jaraco/keyrings.alt) but have no idea how to use it.
So, my question is:

1. Is it possible to use keyring in cx_Freeze ?
2. How do I use the keyrings.alt ?
3. If keyring cannot be used in cx_Freeze, is there anyway of converting py files to exe file that has keyring import in them ?

**My setup code for cx_Freeze is below.**

```
import sys
import os from cx_Freeze
import setup, Executable 
build_exe_options = {"packages":["keyring","selenium"]}
setup(name = "Name",version = "0.1",description = "Description",options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},executables = [Executable(script="target.py")])
```

Answer (score 3):

Following code worked for me with cx_freeze.

```
import keyring
from keyring.backends import Windows
keyring.set_keyring(Windows.WinVaultKeyring())
```

In setup.py script for cx_freeze add "keyring" in "packages" list.

Comment: You are a life saver :)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04.6 I solved this issue first taking a look at what was failing with:

```
python -c "import keyring.backends.SecretService as SS; SS.Keyring.priority"
(...)
RuntimeError: The Secret Service daemon is neither running nor activatable through D-Bus
```

Ref: https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/issues/258

And then these were the steps I followed (most probably you just need to do 3.):
[1.] `sudo apt-get install -y python-dbus`.
[2.] `pip install secretstorage`.
3. `sudo apt install gnome-keyring`.